# VBa Excel IE cant find Table in innerHTML

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to copy a table from a webpage. I cant copy the whole page since its has button and dynamic elements, and pasting those into a sheet breaks the code due to memory overload, so I am trying to pull the HTML and paste just the table into excel.

When I copy the whole source code text into Word, it tells me there is ~23k letters, but when I use innerHTML or outerHTML, they both hover around 15-16k in length.

I know the inner and outer are missing alot of the functions and such from outside the HTML body, but what is baffling me is that they are missing the table that I need in the middle of the code.

Website code:

```
<div class="row" >
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" >


            </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" >
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped " >
                            <thead>
                                <tr style="background:#eee">
                                    <th class="sortable" ><a href="/employer/report/report?_action_report=Run+Report&amp;show_advertisers=on&amp;_show_conversions=&amp;advertiser_id=25&amp;_show_advertisers=&amp;_hide_campaigns=&amp;_show_campaigns=&amp;end=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;campaign_id=&amp;begin=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;sort=day&amp;order=asc">Date</a></th>



                                    <th class="sortable" ><a href="/employer/report/report?_action_report=Run+Report&amp;show_advertisers=on&amp;_show_conversions=&amp;advertiser_id=25&amp;_show_advertisers=&amp;_hide_campaigns=&amp;_show_campaigns=&amp;end=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;campaign_id=&amp;begin=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;sort=jobs&amp;order=asc">Current Jobs Listed</a></th>

                                    <th class="sortable" ><a href="/employer/report/report?_action_report=Run+Report&amp;show_advertisers=on&amp;_show_conversions=&amp;advertiser_id=25&amp;_show_advertisers=&amp;_hide_campaigns=&amp;_show_campaigns=&amp;end=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;campaign_id=&amp;begin=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;sort=impressions&amp;order=asc">Impressions</a></th>
                                    <th class="sortable" ><a href="/employer/report/report?_action_report=Run+Report&amp;show_advertisers=on&amp;_show_conversions=&amp;advertiser_id=25&amp;_show_advertisers=&amp;_hide_campaigns=&amp;_show_campaigns=&amp;end=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;campaign_id=&amp;begin=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;sort=clicks&amp;order=asc">Clicks</a></th>

                                    <th class="sortable" ><a href="/employer/report/report?_action_report=Run+Report&amp;show_advertisers=on&amp;_show_conversions=&amp;advertiser_id=25&amp;_show_advertisers=&amp;_hide_campaigns=&amp;_show_campaigns=&amp;end=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;campaign_id=&amp;begin=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;sort=cpc&amp;order=asc">CPC</a></th>
                                    <th class="sortable" ><a href="/employer/report/report?_action_report=Run+Report&amp;show_advertisers=on&amp;_show_conversions=&amp;advertiser_id=25&amp;_show_advertisers=&amp;_hide_campaigns=&amp;_show_campaigns=&amp;end=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;campaign_id=&amp;begin=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;sort=ctr&amp;order=asc">CTR</a></th>
                                    <th class="sortable" ><a href="/employer/report/report?_action_report=Run+Report&amp;show_advertisers=on&amp;_show_conversions=&amp;advertiser_id=25&amp;_show_advertisers=&amp;_hide_campaigns=&amp;_show_campaigns=&amp;end=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;campaign_id=&amp;begin=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;sort=cost&amp;order=asc">Estimated cost</a></th>

                                    <th class="sortable" ><a href="/employer/report/report?_action_report=Run+Report&amp;show_advertisers=on&amp;_show_conversions=&amp;advertiser_id=25&amp;_show_advertisers=&amp;_hide_campaigns=&amp;_show_campaigns=&amp;end=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;campaign_id=&amp;begin=03%2F11%2F2015&amp;sort=daily_budget&amp;order=asc">Current Daily Budget</a></th>
                                    <th style="vertical-align:top" ><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Edit Campaign</a></th>
                                    <th style="vertical-align:top" ></th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                    <tr class="odd 2015-03-11">
                                        <td>2015-03-11</td>



                                        <td class="jobsListed" >437879</td>

                                        <td>148397</td>
                                        <td>1379</td>

                                        <td>$0.36</td>
                                        <td>0.93%</td>
                                        <td >$491.16</td>

                                        <td class="dailyBudget">$15500.00</td>
                                        <td ><a href="/employer/campaign/">Edit</a></td>

                                    </tr>

                                <tr class="dg" >

                                    <td  colspan="1"  class="text-right"><b>Total:</b></td>

                                    <td class="jobsListed" >437879</td>

                                    <td>148397</td>
                                    <td>1379</td>

                                    <td>$0.36</td>
                                    <td>0.93%</td>
                                    <td >$491.16</td>

                                    <td class="dailyBudget">$15500.00</td>
                                    <td ></td>
                                    <td ></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

        </div>


        </div><!--container ends here -->
```

And here is how I am trying to get the table data:

```
Dim appIE As Object ' InternetExplorer.Application
Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


    Dim strSource As String
    Dim TableString As String
    strSource = CStr(appIE.document.body.outerHTML)
    TableString = Mid(strSource, _
    InStr(strSource, "<table"), _
    InStr(strSource, "</table>") - InStr(strSource, "<table"))

    Dim ClipBoard As New DataObject
    ClipBoard.SetText TableString
    ClipBoard.PutInClipboard
```

It gives me an error since it cannot find `<table` in the string. I stepped through the string a few times, and found that the space where the table should be looks like this:

```
 class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">


            </div>

        </div>


        </div><!--container ends here -->
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the table is dynamic, and not served unless you "hover" over a certain area? This is just a wild guess based on the descriptive class name, without the URL it's hard for anyone to offer specific assistance.  I would ask why are you using string functions to parse HTML? Use a proper DOM parser for HTML or XML documents, which have awesome methods like `.getElementsByClassName` and other methods *designed* specifically for traversing the nodes in an XML/HTML tree.

Comment: I have tried to get it by class name, something similar to this: `strSource = cstr(appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("table table-hover table-bordered table-striped").innerhtml)`
But it still give me an empty table

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem was!

IE was loading the page visually, but the machine still thought it was on the login screen. The way I was able to see this was through `appIE.LocationURL` in the Immediate Window.

So it makes sense that it could not find the table on the page, because it does not exist on the login page.

The solution to this problem is simple really.

1. Check to see if the machine thinks it is at the Login page or Data Page
2. If it is not the login - recreate the IE application and load a new window
   and page. (This will already be logged in however, so make sure
   there is a check to see if you are already logged in. I did this by
   looking for specific text on the page that I know is only on the
   data page and not on the Login page.)
3. Make sure to close all the IE windows - as now just doing `appIE.Quit` will only close the most recent widow.
4. Make sure you have an error handle or this might loop forever.

Code:

```
MakeIE:
set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
...
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    .Visible = True
    .Height = 500
    .Width = 500
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    ' loop until the page finishes loading
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
End With
....
If appIE.LocationURL <> sURL Then GoTo MakeIE
```

Code to kill aLL IE windows (use with caution - WILL KILL ALL IE):

```
Option Explicit
Sub IE_Sledgehammer()
    Dim objWMI As Object, objProcess As Object, objProcesses As Object
    Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://.")
    Set objProcesses = objWMI.ExecQuery( _
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'iexplore.exe'")
    For Each objProcess In objProcesses
        On Error Resume Next
        Call objProcess.Terminate
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    Set objProcesses = Nothing: Set objWMI = Nothing
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
End Sub
```